# Asymptotic size for the number of terms not exceeding $n$ in the class $r$ for a classification of the type Erdös-Selfridge for square-free integers

Tags: analytic-number-theory, asymptotics, integer-sequences, divisors-multiples, square-free

It is possible to define a classification similar than the Erdös-Selfridge classification of primes for different sequences. Please ee [1], section **A18** and the references cited in this book. Because the same definition works for different sequences.

I would like to know if we can to study how works the definition of the mentioned classification now for the so-called square-free integers, or squarefree, (I add as reference for all users interested in the question the Wikipedia [*Square-free integer*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer). I think that the sequence of squarefree integers has a good mathematical, because it is related to some unsolved problems in analytic number theory.

> **Question.** I am curious about if it is possible to get a similar statement than is showed in the second paragraph of section of the book concerning the Erdös-Selfridge classification of primes, thus now for the size of the number of square-free integers $\leq x$ for each class $r\geq 1$. **Many thanks.**

If the question is very difficult feel free to add what work can be done about the asymptotic law that I evoke.

### References:

[1] Richard K. Guy, Unsolved Problems in Number Theory, Unsolved problems in Intuitive Mathematics Volume I, Second Edition, Springer-Verlag (1994).

Comment: I can read a free preview of the mentioned classification, search the words *The Erdös-Selfridge classification of primes* in [Google Books.](https://books.google.com/?hl=en)